# add create and edit icons in front of each node on hover

Tags: jquery, jstree

I want to add a capability to my [**jstree**](https://github.com/vakata/jstree) instance So that in front of each node display icons with custom actions like **create multi node** , **delete** , **edit** and etc on node mouse hovering like this picture : 
[image]

This is my Codes :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $treeview = $('#jstree_demo_div');

    $treeview.on("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {
        $(this).jstree("open_all");
    });

    $treeview.jstree({
        
        "core": {
            "check_callback": true
        },
        "checkbox": {
            "keep_selected_style": false
        },
        "plugins": ["checkbox", "dnd" , "contextmenu"]
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>

<div id="jstree_demo_div" style="direction: rtl">
        <ul>
            <li>sport
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">football</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">basketbal</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>learning
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">html</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">css</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

I there any way to add this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not post any code I will give you the idea. I guess you have a list with all those nodes. I suggest to add in those nodes `<li>leaf node x-y</li>` more items with display:none.

After bind an event on mouseenter for those `<li>` and remove the display:none for the display you may need (display:block i.e)

Here i let you a simple jsfiddle that works as idea. You will have to change it little bit and use your images etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/5yduexox/

Comment: yes i know that it is easy with jquery or css to show and hide icons, but i do not know how to control events of those . what about those? I edited my post with codes .

Comment: Here i updated jsfiddle with your code. I Added an image (which you will have to put your local path to the image) and added a click event controller over images, where you will have to write the code you need. Here you can test it. https://jsfiddle.net/5yduexox/2/

Comment: after trying your suggestion , I face a new problem. when I want to text of a node , html code of icons(img) that are in node shown. but I want only to edit text of node , see it : https://jsfiddle.net/57oyr306/